# SWF downloads twice in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, flash, swfobject

I see SWFs download twice in IE, but not in Chrome. I'm using IE 11. I can see the download requests in the F12 dev tools Network tab and in server access logs. Below is a simple example that exhibits the problem. I'm using [swfobject 2.2](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_2_2.zip&can=2&q=). I've tried calling `swfobject.switchOffAutoHideShow()` before calling `swfobject.embedSWF()`, but that doesn't help.

You can test this by putting the HTML and swfobject.js in the same directory and browsing from the disk, so you don't need an HTTP server to test/reproduce this.

**Does anyone know why this happens and how to stop the second download?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Version</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.adobe.com/swf/software/flash/about/flashAbout_info_small.swf",
        "flashInfo", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="flashInfo">
      <p>No flash here. Move along.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does it show 2 SWFs in the page? - I don't think so, I think it's normal since the example in the swfobject site shows the same behavior http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/testsuite_2_2/test_dynamic.html

Comment: @Roman No, just displays 1 SWF. That test page is essentially the same as my example other than the doctype stuff, so I guess doctype isn't a likely cause.